# If operator doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From RUBY ON RAILS TUTORIAL, Michael Hartl.Chapter 7
I have one problem.If operator doesn't work
I have tried to do new app,but still nothing
application.html.erb:

```
    <nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
      <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

session_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def remember(user)

    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts(page: params[:page])
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

I guess `logged_in`doesn't work, but I could not find a mistake.
When I defining Log out method, the button doesn't change from 'Log in'

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Okay, thank's a lot

Comment: Please post your stacktrace

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

How does your ApplicationController look like?

Before `logged_in?` is to work, you need to include it as a `helper_method`. Something like this, inside your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
  helper_method :logged_in?
end
```

[Here is the documentation for `helper_method`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method)

Comment: Tip: to format your class properly, highlight the entire code and then click `{}` in the editor.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In `current_user` method of `SessionsHelper` module, use following code

```
if (user_id == session[:user_id])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
elsif (user_id == cookies.signed[:user_id])
  user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
  if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
    log_in user
    @current_user = user
  end
end
```

You have used `=` operator for comparison instead of `==`.